# Can i setup mailchamp api on localhost for testing purpose?

Tags: php, xampp

My question is can I setup mailchamp api on localhost for testing purpose?

My localhost server is xampp and I want to use mailchamp api in cakephp.

Can anyone help me for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this can help you: [cackephp-mailchimp](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-mailchimp)

Comment: Thank you for answer but my first question is can i setup mailchamp api on localhost for testing purpose?

Comment: Sorry I forgot answer this, yes I had use this api in localhost, you only need configure the public and private key.